# Matlab compiler and Database application

Tags: matlab, postgresql

I have a Matlab function that retrieves data from a postgres database, manipulate it and writes the result back. When I run the code in Matlab it works like sunshine but when I deploy the code with the compiler an run it it returns an error:

> Error using datastore
>   No value was given for 'SELECT exp_id, exp_name FROM experiments WHERE exp_post_process = '1''. Name-value pair arguments require a name followed by a value.
>
> Error in datastore>parseFileBasedNVPairs (line 244)
>
> Error in datastore (line 102)
>
> Error in Tracker_dbase_conn1 (line 47)
>
> MATLAB:InputParser:ParamMissingValue

This is the code I wrote in Matlab that as mentioned works just fine if I run it:

```
%% Local specifications
%establish database connection%
conn=database('wofog','DBA','','Vendor','PostgreSQL','Server','localhost:5432');
%Selects the name and ID of the experiment that has to be post-processed
%The experiment has been flagged in exp_post_process

sqlqueryExp = ('SELECT exp_id, exp_name FROM experiments WHERE exp_post_process = ''1''');

dbExp = datastore(conn,sqlqueryExp);

exp =read(dbExp);

expID=exp.exp_id;

expName = exp.exp_name;
```

I work on a mac with osx 10.12.5 and Matlab R2017a

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the problem is something to do with a database driver not being present in the compiled application.

To explain what seems to be happening:

- The error message indicates that `datastore` is interpreting its second argument as the first (Name) element of a Name-Value pair argument, and there is no second (Value) element to go with it.
- There are two versions of the `datastore` command - one from base MATLAB that creates `FileDatastore`, and one from Database Toolbox that creates a `DatabaseDatastore`.
- The command from Database Toolbox takes the form `datastore(conn, sqlquery)`, and is called when the first input argument to `datastore` is a valid database connection.
- The command from base MATLAB takes the form `datastore(location, Name, Value, ...)`, and is called otherwise.
- Therefore, since your error message indicates that the second argument is being misinterpreted as the first element of a Name-Value pair, that means that it's the command from base MATLAB that must be being called.
- Therefore, the first input argument can't be a valid database connection.

So why isn't `conn` a valid database connection? I don't know. You could help to diagnose things by putting in a couple of debugging commands after `conn=database(...` that would display `conn` and some of its properties. I'm pretty sure you'll find that it's not a valid database connection object, and then the task is to figure out why.

I might be wrong, but I'm guessing that the ultimate issue will be that the Postgres database driver is available when you're in MATLAB, but not when you're in the compiled application.

Database drivers are typically `.jar` files and, unusually for a `.jar` file, they typically need to be placed on MATLAB's static java path (not the dynamic java path) in order to work properly. It's possible that the Postgres driver is on the MATLAB static path, but isn't being put on the static path of the MATLAB Runtime (MCR) when you're running the compiled application.

If it turns out that this *is* the root cause, you can modify the static path of the MCR in `<mcrinstalllocation>\toolbox\local\classpath.txt`, and directly add the path to the Postgres driver.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Sam, I found the classpath.txt and added the driver's full path, but the result is the same. I tried "$matlabroot/Drivers/postgresql-9.4-1200.jdbc4.jar" and "/Drivers/postgresql-9.4-1200.jdbc4.jar".

Comment: OK - perhaps it's a slightly different issue. Did you try adding some debugging commands in, just after the `conn=database(...` to check whether `conn` is actually a valid connection?

Comment: The application shows a message and shuts down if the contact to the database fails. I found a little work around, I changed the datastore command with the fetch command an it seems to work, that means now it gives another error further in the code, but it has nothing to do with the database. Thank you again for your help.